# Shallow push on Netlify reloads the whole page

Tags: next.js, netlify

When I shallow push router like

```
router.push(url, undefined, {shallow:true})
```

it works fine on local, but reloads the whole page specifically on netlify server, any suggestions?

Comment: Shallow routing only works within the same page - see https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats. Are you pushing to a different page? Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: no im pushing in the same route

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in that case. Hard to tell what's wrong currently.